# Possible issues with using common protocol ports for port forwarding?

Tags: networking, ftp, port-forwarding, port, nat

I am hosting a FileZilla FTP Server on my local Windows machine for some quick file sharing, but I'm in a NAT network and the port 21 from my local machine gets translated to some port e.g. 12345, which is not the default FTP port, so users have to access my server with ftp://publicip:12345/file as opposed to just ftp://publicip/file.

I was wondering if there would be any particular issues with forwarding external port 21 on my modem to my local port 21 just for ease of use in the URL as shown above, considering that I do not run a FTP server anywhere else on this network. I'm asking this because the modem always warns me during port forwarding about this port being a common protocol port, and apparently recommends not to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that all incoming traffic on port 21 will be sent directly to your computer. This is what you want but I'm not sure it's safe. You have to be really confident that your FileZilla server is setup in a secure fashion.

Encrypted connections and strong passwords only protect the data. Your PC could be at risk if there is a flaw in FileZilla. For example CVE-2007-2318:

> "Multiple format string vulnerabilities in FileZilla before 2.2.32
>   allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via format string
>   specifiers"

This attack did not require authentication. So anyone scanning the internet for this vulnerability could see your FileZilla server and use it to take over your computer.

If you're going to run anything facing the internet you gotta keep it patched up and watch the vulnerability databases for known exploits occuring in the wild.

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2889/Filezilla.html

So go ahead and forward that port but just know the risk you are taking.

Comment: Well I don't really have any interest in securing the data because it's mostly for quick non-sensitive image and file sharing with friends so I'm using plain FTP with anonymous login and fixed reasonable user count/bandwidth usage limits, plus read-only mode for everything. Thank you for the insight, I'll make sure to keep the server up to date. I will also firewall the port to only accept connections from Brazil (me and my friends's location) in order to prevent possible DDoS attacks.

Comment: Please don't leave anonymous login open to the internet. Anyone can proxy their connection to pretend to be from Brazil. You need a password strong enough to keep bots and scanners out. Open authentication largely increases your attack surface.